# How to split a list item in python

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a list like the following:

```
names= ["my name xyz","your name is abc","her name is cfg zyx"]
```

I want to split them like following:

```
my_array[0]= ["my","name","xyz"]
my_arrray[1]= ["your","name","is","abc"]
my_array[2]= ["her","name","is","cfg","zyx"]
```

So that I can choose the words individually like following:

```
my_array[0][0]= my
my_array[0][1]= name
my_array[1][2]= is
my_array[0][2]= xyz
```

The python code i tried is following:

```
names_abc= names.splitlines(True)
#print(names_abc)

i=0
while i < len(names_abc):
    my_array= names_abc[i].split()
    print(my_array[0])
    i=i+1
```

But this code doesn't do what I expect. It splits the list but cannot choose the words individually. For example, the output of the above code is following:

my
your
her

which is definitely wrong. I will be grateful to get a help from the python experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do it in one line with a list comprehension.

Comment: BTW, the `while` loop is probably the wrong choice in Python unless it is `while True`, 99% of the time you should use the `for` loop and the iterator protocol instead.

Answer (score 5):

You could define `my_array` using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_array = [phrase.split() for phrase in names]
```

which is equivalent to

```
my_array = list()
for phrase in names:
    my_array.append(phrase.split())
```

---

Demo:

```
In [21]: names= ["my name xyz","your name is abc","her name is cfg zyx"]

In [22]: my_array = [phrase.split() for phrase in names]

In [23]: my_array
Out[23]: 
[['my', 'name', 'xyz'],
 ['your', 'name', 'is', 'abc'],
 ['her', 'name', 'is', 'cfg', 'zyx']]

In [24]: my_array[0][1]
Out[24]: 'name'
```

---

One problem with defining `my_array` this way:

```
while i < len(names_abc):
    my_array= names_abc[i].split()
```

is that `my_array` is assigned to a new list each time through the `while-loop`. So `my_array` does not become a list of lists. Instead, after the `while-loop`, it only retains its last value.

Instead of printing `my_array[0]`, try `print(my_array)` itself. It might become more clear why you're getting the result you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

You could `split()` every element in your list, which by default will split on spaces.

```
>>> names= ["my name xyz","your name is abc","her name is cfg zyx"]
>>> [i.split() for i in names]
[['my', 'name', 'xyz'], ['your', 'name', 'is', 'abc'], ['her', 'name', 'is', 'cfg', 'zyx']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new list and fill it with lists containing temporaray strings build from the characters of your starting list.

The temporary string is ended by the space, when a string is complete it is added to a temoprary list (list_tmp).

After all items are processed as strings and added to the temporary list, we append that list the final list:

```
a=["my name xyz","your name is abc","her name is cfg zyx"]

l=[]

for i in enumerate(a):
        tmp_str = ''
        list_tmp=[]
        for j in i[1]:
                if " " in j:
                        list_tmp.append(tmp_str)
                        tmp_str=''
                else:
                        tmp_str+=j
        else:
                list_tmp.append(tmp_str)

        l.append(list_tmp)

print l
print l[0][1]
```