# index error while running a loop over list contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
my_array= ["*","device",":","xyz"], ["+","asd","=","10","pdf","=","6"],
["+","dsa","=","1","pqa","=","2","dga","=","12"], ["*"]
```

What I want to do is:

```
define('device','xyz')
define('asd','10')
define('pdf','6')
define('dsa','1')
define('pqa','2')
define('dga','12')
```

The way I approached is:

```
i=0
while i < len(my_array):
    if my_array[i][0]=="*":
          print("'",my_array[i][1],"'","'",my_array[i][3:],"'")
    elif my_array[i][0]=="+":
          print("'",my_array[i][1],"'","'",my_array[i][3],"'")
          if my_array[i][4]=="\D":
              print("'",my_array[i][4],"'","'",my_array[i][6],"'")
          elif my_array[i][7]=="\D":
              print("'",my_array[i][7],"'","'",my_array[i][9],"'")
i=i+1
```

But doing this, I get index error. I know where the problem is, but I cannot fix it with my very bad programming brain. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: provide full traceback.

Comment: Well what is `["*"][1]` or `["+","asd","=","10","pdf","=","6"][7]` supposed to give you? I suspect this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248731) - could you give a broader view of what you're trying to achieve? Where does `my_array` come from?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range. I know i get this error message for my_array[4], because I only have one element "*". So my_array[4][1] is empty.

Comment: So test the length of `my_array[i]` before you try to access nonexistent elements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i had a hspice file. I read it in python and then splitted the strings. afterwards i got my_array. To split it I used the following codes:

    a_content_lines= a_content.splitlines(True)
    #print(a_content_lines)
    my_array = [phrase.split() for phrase in a_content_lines]

Comment: So having looked at your previous questions, it seems that you're trying to write a parser. This is useful context for a question. Is the problem this question is about the same as [the one you were trying to solve by padding with `" "`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946228/splitting-list-with-equal-contents)? I asked you there to provide context, too - when people ask for broader context, we don't just want the line before the one that fails, we want to know *what you are trying to achieve*.

Answer (score 1):

First review problem seems in

```
if my_array[i][0]=="*":
      print("'",my_array[i][1],"'","'",my_array[i][3:],"'")
```

because last element in your `my_array` is `['*']` and it has no other elements and u are trying to access `my_array['*'][1]` and its give index error.

You have to remove that element or add members who fulfill element index requirement.

Comment: This has already been pointed out in comments. Are you going to tell him how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding the indices is a sure sign you're doing something wrong - the items in `my_array` have variable lengths, so some of your indices inevitably fail. I think what you want is something like:

```
for command in my_array:
    if command[0] in ("*", "+"):
        for start in range(1, len(command), 3):
            assignment = command[start:start+3]
            if assignment[1] in ("=", ":"):
                print assignment[0], assignment[2]
```

It is worth noting, however, that you seem to be attempting to write a file parser. Although this code solves this specific problem, it is likely that your overall approach could be improved.

Comment: I am just a novice in programming. can you please help me to get the output which I require. it will be really helpful.

Comment: @genocide_in_hell in what way is this *not* helping you to get the output that you require? SO isn't actually here to help you write a program [step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939011/how-to-split-a-list-item-in-python) by [tiny step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946228/splitting-list-with-equal-contents).

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption, that every key in your list has a value attached to it(e.g. there are no two asterisk following after each other) you can make some simplifications:

We'll read the first value as a key of a new dict and the second item as the value.
With the newly tidied up dict(d) you can continue to work easily e.g. in a for loop:

```
array=["*","device",":","xyz"], ["+","asd","=","10","pdf","=","6"],
       ["+","dsa","=","1","pqa","=","2","dga","=","12"], ["*"]

d = {}

for list in array:
        new_key = None
        for item in list:
                if item in ['*',':','+','=']: continue
                if new_key == None:
                        new_key = item
                else:
                        d[new_key] = item
                        new_key = None


for key in d:
        define(key,d[key])
```